# Why tables in a DB are not created Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a table name by date

```
import requests, json, sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('parser_all.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'

full_page = requests.get(url, auth=("admin","admin"))
pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))

a = []
for i in pars:
    a.append(i["date_visit"])

unique = list(set(a))

def get_registers(unique):
    for i in range(len(unique)):
        register =  unique[i]
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + register + ' (name STRING )')
        cursor.close()

get_registers(unique)
```

sample data in a ['13-04-2020', '10-04-2020'].

***in the end I get an error***

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + register + ' (name STRING )')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "13": syntax error
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. What is `13` that's coming in the error? Also, print what's coming in `register`?

Comment: use TEXT instead of STRING

Comment: @MayankPorwal 13 most likely day in date

Answer (score 1):

In your case SQL engine receive query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 13-04-2020 (name STRING )
```

and return error because `13-04-2020` is expression, not a valid table name

You can fix it by quote table name like `"13-04-2020"`:

```js
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "' + register + '" (name STRING )')
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8347bc7345f2b16036fe539c75ebdb7a)

Comment: STRING is not a SQLite datatypes it will raise another exception

Comment: it seems like SQLite ignores any unknown type and replaces it with TEXT, try to put any value in the type and it will work, but it remains invalid, as specified on the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/datatype3.html)